# Display text in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am developing a MVC application in C# and and have a question about displaying text in a view.

I have the following code that does work:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Book.Name)
```

Here is the code that I have written that does not work:

```
Book Name: @Html.DisplayText(model => model.Book.Name)
```

May I have some help to get the correct syntax for the above code? I am wanting to display the contents of the model.Book.Name as simple text.

Comment: There is nothing called DisplayText. Use DisplayFor helper method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Book Name: @Html.DisplayFor(model =>  model.Book.Name)
```